# Apply rule to text but not within div or element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, str-replace

so I basically want to manipulate a **specific tag** in the containing html of a textarea (using just javascript) without touching the rest, for example:

```
<textarea>    
    some stuff here
    random new line

    <i>this can be treated as
    per other text and manipulated</i>

    <b>
    BUT something 
    in bold 
    should be ignored / overlooked</b>

    and some
    other stuff,
    right here

</textarea>
```

Suppose I wanted to replace all new lines `\n` in this textarea (with a `<br/>`), but wanted to IGNORE the text in the `<b>` (and just the `<b>` tag, not just any HTML tag), how would I go about this?

I was thinking some kind of regex could work but wasn't sure about how to put the rule together... although parsing html through regex isn't ideal - if it works then it solves my issue. I also thought some kind of jquery juggling between `.text()` and `.html()` could work with some `:not()` and `.filter()` perhaps but I'm stuck for where to even start really...

Many thanks

Comment: ... *"...replace all new lines `\n` in this..."* with what? `<br>` ?

Comment: Replace all new lines, with what? Should empty `<b>` tags be left?

Comment: Yes a `<br/>`, sorry. `<b>` tags need to remain as they are.

Comment: Have updated the code bit with some wording for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not claiming that this is the correct or the best approach, but here is a regular expression that will do what you require.

The following will replace any `\n` with `<br/>` provided that looking ahead in the string a `</b>` does not appear before a `<b>` - this will prevent any replacements inside `<b></b>`.

```
text = text.replace( /\n(?!((?!<b>)[\s\S])*<\/b>)/g , '<br/>' );
```

Example

```
$('textarea').val( function ( index, old ) {
    return old.replace( /\n(?!((?!<b>)[\s\S])*<\/b>)/g , '<br/>' );
});
```

Comment: @Tim. Change the `<b>` in the regex to e.g. `<b[^>]*>`.